# Problem with turtlebot computers setup

Tags: ros, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am encountering problems when trying to set up the computers for running a turtlebot.
Here is the setup info:

Turtlebot netbook - Electric - 192.168.1.3 (tbot)
Workstation - Groovy - 192.168.1.2 (work)

ROS_MASTER_URI : "http://192 . 168 . 1 . 3:11311"
ROS_IP : "192 . 168 . 1 . 3"

(set on both computers)

I can ssh into tbot from work and viceversa. I can ping both machines from each other. netcat listening works fine. But using "rostopic list" on the workstation gives out "Unable to communicate with master!" error.

Also, according to the tutorials, if I use "rostopic echo /diagnostics" on the netbook, it should report a warning saying that "diagnostics has not been published", but in this case, it just prints some diagnostic info saying that dev/ttyUSB0 is not connected.

roscore is indeed running on 192.168.1.3:11311, but the workstation is unable to find it. Looking forward to your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57622/problem-with-turtlebot-computers-setup/) by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2013-03-09**:
The master is usually port 11311, are you sure yours is 11611?

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-03-09**:
Sorry, that was a typo. I typed this from Windows. Corrected.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-14**:
Does Windows not support "3" any more? :-D

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-03-14**:
No, I meant I forgot what the port was as I was in Windows and couldn't run roscore to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

As I mentioned, I did a clean install of linux on the turtlebot and installed ROS Groovy and the turtlebot apps, and the setup started working. Thanks for your comments.

---

Originally posted by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) with karma: 275 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-14**:
congratulations